# Is it possible through Spring to generate a wsdl with multiple services?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I've **four** Soap endpoints in **one** class in my application. Each of them has its own xsd file. There is also **one** configuration class, where **all** endpoints are described. Spring generates wsdl only for endpoint that is **described first** in configuration class. Is it even possible using ***Spring*** to generate **one wsdl for all endpoints** (*Soap services*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will generate one wsdl file if all requests and responses are located in one xsd file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="qualified"
            xmlns:tns="qualified">

        <xsd:element name="Request1">
            </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Response1">
            </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Request2">
            </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Response2">
            </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```